# C# get max value for Socket.ReceiveBufferSize and Socket.SendBufferSize on a system

Tags: c#, sockets

Our high throughput application (~1gbps) benefits greatly from a large ReceiveBufferSize and SendBufferSize.

I noticed on my machine I can have a 100 MB buffer size with no problems but on some client and test machines the max value is a little over 10 MB and seems to be variable.

Are there any methods to query the system what the max tx/rx buffer size can be.

Comment: What method did you use to determine the limits?

Comment: @Fantius, I believe the Joe might have just obtained those values by playing around with the buffer sizes.

Comment: Yeah, It was just trial and error, I assume the environment has a lot to do with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually for high performance networking the [`SO_RCVBUF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SO_SNDBUF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) options should be set to 0 to avoid buffer copies, as per [KB181611](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181611):

> If you use the SO_RCVBUF and SO_SNDBUF
>   option to set zero TCP stack receive
>   and send buffer, you basically
>   instruct the TCP stack to directly
>   perform I/O using the buffer provided
>   in your I/O call. Therefore, in
>   addition to the nonblocking advantage
>   of the overlapped socket I/O, the
>   other advantage is **better performance
>   because you save a buffer copy between
>   the TCP stack buffer and the user
>   buffer for each I/O call**. But you have
>   to make sure you don't access the user
>   buffer once it's submitted for
>   overlapped operation and before the
>   overlapped operation completes.

The max values you can set these options (which are the real setting behind the managed [`Socket.ReceiveBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize.aspx#Y246)) are 'implementation dependent'. Other TCP parameters are documented at [TCP/IP Registry Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921093.aspx).

Comment: Is it recommended to set Socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 0 on Win XP - Win 7? It's a bit strange that the default value is 8K when 0 could be a better setting.

Comment: After browsing the TCP/IP Registry Settings pages from your link, I was not able to find the max buffer size. Does anyone know what it's called?

Comment: The default 8K is for run-of-the-mill apps. Writing high perf apps is different in many aspects. http://rusanu.com/2008/11/11/high-performance-windows-programs/

Comment: @Remus, Excellent resource and excellent answer! Thank you for all this information and these links. Does setting the buffer to 0 have any ill effects on pre-vista OS's?

Comment: Doesn't have ill effects, but your app has to behave accordingly. See the note about 'you have to make sure you don't access the user buffer once it's submitted'.

Comment: @Remus, I'm doing some testing on this. Since I'm calling Socket.Send from managed code (.net), I think it's possible a copy is happening during the pinvoke under the scenes. If that is the case the 'you have to make sure you don't access the user buffer once it's submitted' may not apply ONLY if you are calling Send from managed code.

Comment: This is also a bit invalid if he was using UDPs.

Comment: This does **not** work for my UDP listener. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483836/cause-of-high-udp-package-loss-on-localhost

Comment: Is it possible to configure the network card's buffer ? In order to avoid losing data

Comment: @Guillaume07 please ask new questions as separate questions, not as comments on old questions

Comment: @RemusRusanu done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496691/set-tcp-stack-buffer-to-0-and-network-interface-buffer

Answer (score 3):

Those two properties internally play with the socket options (via `SetSocketOption`, eventually to the native [`setsockopt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). If memory serves these are going to depend on the non-paged pool memory available (which changes machine to machine) and potentially which network driver is on each machine.

Regardless, you actually aren't guaranteed that the buffer size you requested is used, you'll have to retrieve the current buffer size after the fact to make sure it was used. Moreover, on Windows 7 and 2008 machines it is my understanding that [your buffers may be dynamically increased/decreased](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379523%28WS.10%29.aspx).

In short, you likely can only test increasing buffer sizes and take the maximum that does not cause an error. There are too many variables at play which could determine the maximum size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really am not a fan of "you likely can only test increasing buffer sizes and take the maximum that does not cause an error." but this does indeed seem to be the case as I cannot find any real answers to my question.